# Split a string by commas but ignore commas within double-quotes using Delphi

Tags: csv, parsing, delphi, split, delphi-11-alexandria

I successfully read the CSV into TStrings using:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

    begin
      SL := TStringList.Create;
      SL.Delimiter := ',';        // default, but ";" is used with some locales
      SL.QuoteChar := '"';        // default
      SL.StrictDelimiter := True; // required: strings are separated *only* by Delimiter
    end;
```

```
20211605344,04/23/2021 - 09:26:42 am,4/28/2021,"Wood Drive, ENFIELD, CT","Calini, CBM",3223837, ENFIELD,Hartford,1,3,No as-built attached

20211300637,03/29/2021 - 11:48:51 am,4/1/2021,"Enfield Street, ENFIELD, CT",CBM,3223846, ENFIELD,Hartford,2,0,Job changed to aerial
```

Now I am trying to read each row into a dynamic array so I can assign each field.

```pascal
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
  TicketNumber:string;
  oneStr: TStringDynArray;
  val:double;
begin
  SL.LoadFromFile('D:\DelphiProjects\ImportCSV\PURA Phase 2 inspection selection.csv');
  for I := 1 to SL.Count-1 do
    begin
      oneStr:= SplitString(SL[i], ',');
      TicketNumber:= oneStr[0];
      If TryStrToFloat(TicketNumber, val)then
        memo2.Lines.Add('TicketNo: '+oneStr[0]+' '+'Job Date: '+oneStr[1]+' '+ 'Job Start: '+oneStr[2]+' '+'Address: '+oneStr[3]+' '+ 'Crew: '+oneStr[4]+' '+'Project: '+oneStr[5]+' '+'Town: '+oneStr[6]+' '+'County: '+oneStr[7]+' '+'Order: '+oneStr[8]+' '+'Count: '+oneStr[9]+' '+'Note: '+oneStr[10]);
    end;   
end;
```

What I am getting is:

```
TicketNo: 20211605344 Job Date: 04/23/2021 - 09:26:42 am Job Start: 4/28/2021 Address: "Wood Drive Crew:  ENFIELD Project:  CT" Town: "Calini County:  CBM" Order: 3223837 Count:  ENFIELD Note: Hartford
TicketNo: 20211300637 Job Date: 03/29/2021 - 11:48:51 am Job Start: 4/1/2021 Address: "Enfield Street Crew:  ENFIELD Project:  CT" Town: CBM County: 3223846 Order:  ENFIELD Count: Hartford Note: 2
```

It is also breaking in the commas within the double quotes!!
How can I prevent this?
Thanks
Delphi 11.2

Comment: You can't prevent it using SplitString - it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do, which is splitting the string at each comma. If you want different behavior, you'll have to write your own code to parse the line of data.

Comment: Thanks Ken,
I simply had my client export as Tab delimited and my problem was solved.  LOL

Answer (score 0):

As Ken White stated, this record would need to be parsed by hand using Pos statements and copy.
But my solution was to have my client export the excel as tab delimited text which allowed me to use #9 as the strict delimiter.